# InsertAfter() fail on empty table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function that transfert row from a table to another table, and vice versa.
This works well but when the table is empty, the fucntion doesn't work anymore.

```
//fonction deplacement du tableauAvant au tableauApres
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table-bougesurApres').click(function (e) {
                 $('#table1 tr.selected').insertAfter('#table2 tbody tr:last-child');
    })
})  


//fonction deplacement du tableauApres au tableauAvant
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table-bougesurAvant').click(function (e) {
                 $('#table2 tr.selected').insertAfter('#table1 tbody tr:last-child');
    })
})
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7o4vzs/

Comment: Then check if there are any childs or not, if not use append :D

Comment: Or just use append it will insert after last one always :D or as first one if there are none

Comment: Thanks man for your answer, but i just had to use .appendTo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use `appendTo()` instead of `insertAfter()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //fonction déplacement du tableau Avant au tableau Après
    $('.table-bougesurApres').click(function (e) {
        $('#table1 tr.selected').appendTo('#table2 tbody');
    });

    //fonction déplacement du tableau Après au tableau Avant
    $('.table-bougesurAvant').click(function (e) {
        $('#table2 tr.selected').appendTo('#table1 tbody');
    });

});
```

Working [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7o4vzs/18/)

Comment: Bienvenue, Luc! Heureux que ça a aidé ... :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table1 tbody tr").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

    $("#table2 tbody tr").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });




//fonction deplacement du tableauAvant au tableauApres
 $('.table-bougesurApres').click(function (e) {
   $('#table2 tbody').append($( "#table1 tr.selected" ));
  })


//fonction deplacement du tableauApres au tableauAvant
 $('.table-bougesurAvant').click(function (e) {            
   $('#table1 tbody').append($( "#table2 tr.selected" ));
  })
})
```

```css
.selected td {
    background: #ffffcf;
}
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="table-bougesurApres">table1 vers table2</button>
<button type="button" class="table-bougesurAvant">table2 vers table1 Selected</button>
<h2>Table1</h2>
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td>Row1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row6</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h2>Table2</h2>
<table id="table2">
<tr>
<td>Row21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row26</td>
</tr>
</table>
```